# Multiple databases or type field

Tags: pouchdb

In PouchDB it appears that it is just a document database and has no concept of tables.

I have 2 types of data: customers and items. I have a type field in my documents so I can filter records.

Would I be better of making 2 databases on PouchDB? Is there any downside to this?

Comment: Both approaches can work. It depends a lot more on your data access patterns than on the data itself.

Comment: Having a single database allows you to make 1 to many joins with maps and allows you to use shared views. IMO, don't complicate yourself and opt for a single database with documents classified by type.